# What is the infimum of this set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I read the article on Infimum and supremum on wiki and came across this example. I am unable to understand Why the infimum of this set should be $-1$.
I think it should be zero.

Can anyone help.
$$
\inf\left\{ (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}\bigg|\ n = 1,2,3,...  \right\} = -1
$$

Comment: You should explain in your post, why you think it should be zero.

Comment: There are also standard English terms for infimum and supremum, which are $glb$ and $lub$ : greatest lower bound and least upper bound.

Comment: There is no such thing as "standard English" for infimum or supremum, but rather just more of a convention as they contain more mathematical information, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, for $n=2k+1$ odd, we have $(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}=-1+\frac{1}{2k+1}$, and for big $k$ those numbers can get arbitrarily close to $-1$. More rigorously:

- On one hand, we have $(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}\ge -1$ for all $n$, so $-1$ is a lower bound of the whole set.
- On the other hand, this is the highest lower bound: if you pick anything higher than that, say $-1+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon\gt 0$, there will be elements of this set "below" that: whenever $2k+1\gt\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, we will have $-1+\frac{1}{2k+1}\lt-1+\epsilon$.

Thus $-1$ is the highest lower bound, i.e. infimum of this set.

Comment: @user2984602 I know, people jump on use of sequences and limits before they've mastered the basics...

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}S&=\left\{(-1)^n+\dfrac1n\bigg|n=1,2,3\cdots\right\}\\&=\begin{cases}-1+\dfrac1n,&n=2k+1\\1+\dfrac1n,&n=2k\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Taking limits as $n\to\infty$
$$\begin{align}S&=\begin{cases}(-1,0],&n=2k+1\\ \left(1,\dfrac32\right]&n=2k\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Hence
$$\begin{align}\sup(S)&=\dfrac32\\\inf(S)&=-1\end{align}$$

Comment: Surely the maximum value attainable is, when k = 1 i.e n = 2
i.e $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @user2984602 does it look okay now?

Comment: Yes it's good, but I approved the other answer as it states the definitions. +1 for adding supremum though.

Comment: @user2984602, no worries. Just wanted to see what I was doing wrong. I had $\dfrac32$ in the beginning. Don't know why I changed it :P